# Ticking noise in PSU even when its turned off

Tags: power-supply, noise

I need some suggestions regarding an issue in case if someone has faced the same.
I have Cooler Master V850 PSU in my system.

Recently It started making this very low volume ticking noise. Its not constant (sometimes it makes it some times it doesn't). Sometimes it makes that noise even when its turned off.

The noise is kind of like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=IH-7-JF24lY&feature=emb_logo) video but **NOT THAT LOUD**. Its in very **LOW VOLUME** and very **LESS FREQUENT**. Mine is kind of like a mouse click but not that much audible.

Its not at all certain when it makes the noise, It makes it very irregularly.

Computer works perfectly fine and there are no issues what so ever but it kind of bugs me and I'm very concerned about it as Its a very expensive (at least for me) piece of hardware in my PC.

If someone has faced a similar problem, Can you suggest me what should I do?
Are there any chances that it might damage the other components like motherboard, ssd or ram?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the video you showed, it sounds like the fan could be hitting something or a bad fan bearing. If it makes the noise when it turns off, it could possibly be an issue with a resistor or something? The next time you have the power off, and it makes the ticking noise, flip the power switch to off or unplug the main cable and see if the noise stops.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you for the reply. I tried that and If I turn off the switch on the PSU, the noise doesn't stop. It stays the same (sometimes makes noise sometimes it doesn't) but if I unplug the cable, it stops. This is so weird.

Comment: After flipping the switch, it may need a few seconds to fully drain the power. It definitely sounds like it may be something related to the board inside of it. After a lot of searching I found a post on [techpowerup](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/psu-clicking-noise-its-not-the-fan-or-coil-whine.250088/). Someone had a similar issue and replaced some resistors which fixed the problem. If you're not experienced with EE, this is not something I would try on your own. I don't even know how they found out which one was the problem.

Comment: @DrZoo thank you for the suggestion. Im not going to open it myself. One last question, how come the pc works without an issue? Or maybe there is an issue but I just cant see it? If I dont repair it, does it mean after sometime it'll die?

Comment: I'm not sure if that means it will eventually fail or not. I did more research on it today and found similar problems on a few sites explaining the potential issue. [Sci.Electronics](https://www.repairfaq.org/REPAIR/F_SwitcherPS.html), look at Section 3, Number 4. [All About Circuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/monitor-not-powering-on-ticking-noise-comming-from-power-board.148255/#:~:text=Ticking%20is%20often%20a%20sign,is%20in%20the%20feedback%20path.), look at the highlighted answer.

Comment: Also one from [EE Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337187/unknown-ticking-sound-on-bad-ite-power-supply). Different type of PSU, same concept. If you'd like you could get an estimate on how much it would cost to fix, or start saving up and buy a new one when you have the money.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you again. There is a slight possibility mentioned in your given links that sometimes it can be caused by dust (basically it kills the components). And the fact that it doesn't make any noise in the morning after being idle overnight and it starts ticking after using it some time, It might be overheating. I'll clean it up with a blower and see if it fixes it. I have a small blower and I'll hold the fan while blowing the air to avoid any damages. I'm sure for one thing though, I'm not going to go for Cooler Master in the future ever again!!

Comment: Sounds good. Hopefully cleaning it out does something. I've always had good luck with Corsair and Seasonic PSUs. EVGA makes some pretty good ones too. Just some brands to keep in mind for the future. Another thing to look at for quality PSUs is their warranty timeframe. If you can get one with 7 or 10 year warranty, it's definitely better quality than the ones with 3-5 year warranty.

Comment: @DrZoo I'm not really sure what happened but here is what I did, Instead of blowing the PSU with a blower, I tried removing the UPS. So I plugged the computer directly into the outlet and I haven't heard a noise ever since. I'll use it for a day or two and see if that was the issue because I'm not 100% sure how could that be an issue. I'll add a comment if It works or not. Thanks for all your help. You can put your comments as an answer here so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: @DrZoo Nope I was wrong, None of those worked for me. I've requested for a replacement from the dealer. If its not possible, I'll probably replace it with Corsair PSU. Thanks.